# How do I use Blue-Green Deployment in Pivotal Web Services?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I read from this guide http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html that this deployment is supported through CLI.

1. Can I use my Pivotal Web Services web interface to do that ?
2. Does the Green instance connect to the production DB ?

Any guide is greatly appreached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes,you can use the web interface to map and unmap routes. When you go to the detail app of your app, you can see at the bottom a tab panel. One of the tabs says 'Routes'. There you can map and unmap routes.
2. Yes, both instances should be connected to the same db. During a time, when both instances are live (the production route is mapped to both of them), you will have users using the old and the new version. If a user is using the old version, you want his/her edits to be stored and present when he/she is switched over to the new version. Note: That means you should make sure that all your database migrations are backwards compatible.

Comment: How do I push / deploy the `new app` to the new route through web interface ? Do I need to create additional space for it ?

Comment: You will have to push the app through the command line interface. The important thing, though, you can manage/map routes to your apps through the user interface.

You do not have to create a new space. Typically, I would think it would be odd if you were to create a new space just for releasing a new prod version of your app. Most often you see spaces used for dev/test/staging/demo/prod separation (although there are other cool ways to use spaces as well).

Comment: Anything I need to configure in the domain ?

Comment: You don't have to configure anything special with the domain.

Comment: Do I have run the CLI command in the root directory of my project ? Thank you !

Comment: That depends on whether you use the `-p` option to point to a path or not. If you don't use the `-p` option, yes, you will have to run that command in your root folder. Here are some tutorials about pushing apps: 
- [Getting Started Deploying Ruby on Rails Apps](http://docs.run.pivotal.io/buildpacks/ruby/gsg-ror.html) 
- [Getting Started Deploying Spring Apps](http://docs.run.pivotal.io/buildpacks/java/gsg-spring.html)
- [For apps using other frameworks or for general guidelines](http://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html)